# Android: Control MediaPlayer instance(object) from outside the app?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I've developed a news android app, this app uses a MediaPlayer class to stream newscast tracks from SoundCloud and everything works fine. Now let's say the user pressed the play button from inside the app and the music starts playing. Now the user pressed the hardware home button and the app went to the background or the user pressed the sleep button to turn off the screen. I have managed to let the music playing in the background but i want the user to be able to control the MediaPlayer from outside the app (pause, stop, next, prev actions).

I searched a lot and didn't find anything, How can i do that?

I didn't put my code because i think it's irrelevant Please tell me if you want to see the code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar by adding a custom notification with images/buttons to control the audio play and channel from the Android notification bar.

I *think* this is what you are after.

Notification code:

```
public Notification buildNotification()
   {
      Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
      PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, 0);

      setContentView();

      Notification.Builder notibuilder = new Notification.Builder(mContext);
         notibuilder.setContentTitle(" ");
         notibuilder.setContentText(" ");
         notibuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
         notibuilder.setOngoing(true);
         notibuilder.setAutoCancel(false);
         notibuilder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
         notibuilder.setContent(mContentView);
         notibuilder.setTicker(null);


         mNotification = notibuilder.build();

      NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

      return mNotification;
   }

   public void setContentView()
   {
      mContentView = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
      mContentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notificaiton_app_title, "");

      String currentChannel = "  ";
      if ( mCurrentChannel != -1)
         currentChannel = " " + (mCurrentChannel + 1);
      mContentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notificaiton_app_channel, currentChannel);

      Intent previousIntent = new Intent(mContext, NotificationButtonIntentService.class);
      previousIntent.setAction(NotificationButtonIntentService.Action_Previous);
      mContentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_layout_previous, PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, previousIntent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
      mContentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_image_previous, PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, previousIntent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));

      Intent playIntent = new Intent(mContext, NotificationButtonIntentService.class);

      if ( mCurrentChannel != -1)
      {
         playIntent.setAction(NotificationButtonIntentService.Action_Pause);
         mContentView.setInt(R.id.notification_image_play_pause, "setBackgroundResource", R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
      }
      else
      {
         playIntent.setAction(NotificationButtonIntentService.Action_Play);
         mContentView.setInt(R.id.notification_image_play_pause, "setBackgroundResource", R.drawable.ic_media_play);
      }

      mContentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_layout_play_pause, PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, playIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
      mContentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_image_play_pause, PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, playIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));

      Intent nextIntent = new Intent(mContext, NotificationButtonIntentService.class);
      nextIntent.setAction(NotificationButtonIntentService.Action_Next);
      mContentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_layout_next, PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, nextIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
      mContentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_image_next, PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, nextIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));

      Intent closeIntent = new Intent(mContext, NotificationButtonIntentService.class);
      closeIntent.setAction(NotificationButtonIntentService.Action_Close);
      mContentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_layout_close, PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, closeIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
      mContentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_image_close, PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, closeIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
   }
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/notification_app_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_stat_zipstreamer" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notificaiton_app_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notificaiton_app_channel"
            style="@style/notification.channel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ems="2" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/notification_layout_previous"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/notification_image_previous"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_media_previous" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/notification_layout_play_pause"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/notification_image_play_pause"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_media_play" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/notification_layout_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/notification_image_next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_media_next" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/notification_layout_close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/notification_image_close"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_media_close" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Intent Service:

```
public class NotificationButtonIntentService extends IntentService
{

   public static final String TAG = "NotificationButtonIntentService";

   public static final String Action_Play = "play";
   public static final String Action_Pause = "pause";
   public static final String Action_Previous = "previous";
   public static final String Action_Next = "next";
   public static final String Action_Close = "close";

   public NotificationButtonIntentService() 
   {
      super("");
   }

   public NotificationButtonIntentService(String name)
   {
      super(name);

   }

   @Override
   protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
   {
      String action = intent.getAction();
      String realAction = intent.getAction();

      if (realAction != null) 
      {
          if (realAction.equals(Action_Play)) 
          {
             EventBus.getDefault().post(new PlayControlEvent(PlayControlEvent.PlayAction.PLAY));    
          } 
          else if (realAction.equals(Action_Pause)) 
          {
             EventBus.getDefault().post(new PlayControlEvent(PlayControlEvent.PlayAction.PAUSE));    
          } 
          else if (realAction.equals(Action_Close)) 
          {
              EventBus.getDefault().post(new ShutdownEvent());
          }
          else if ( realAction.equals(Action_Next))
          {
             EventBus.getDefault().post(new PlayControlEvent(PlayControlEvent.PlayAction.NEXT_CHANNEL));
          }
          else if ( realAction.equals(Action_Previous))
          {
             EventBus.getDefault().post(new PlayControlEvent(PlayControlEvent.PlayAction.PREVIOUS_CHANNEL));
          }
      }
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! for that i'll try it, but just a question: if the user plays music from another app, how can i stop my MediaPlayer from playing to prevent interfering with that other player ?

Comment: For that you will need to utilize and honor Android's audio focus, it is fairly easy: http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html

Comment: Thanks!, and do you recommend making a lock screen widget as well ?,
or the user can control the player even while the screen is locked ?

Comment: The notification code that I posed above does appear on the Lollipop lock screen and the player can be controlled while locked.  This is a Lollipop standard feature since I did nothing special to make it appear there.

Comment: and for android under 5.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

You need yo access your MediaPlayer object. make it static and create your static pause,start,etc methods. something like this:

```
public class myMediaPlayer{
static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;

public static void start(final Context context, Uri media){
  mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
  mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, media);
  mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MEDIA);
  mediaPlayer.prepare();
  mediaPlayer.start();
}

public static void stop() {
  if(mediaPlayer!=null)
    mediaPlayer.release();
}
```

Comment: Yes i have made a custom class that play, pauses and resets the player, but i want to use it outside the app like a widget or in the notification, i don't know which is the better way to do it

Comment: i think widget is better, consider Lock Screen Widget